# Overriding the inline CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDiv">

//Some content

</div>
```

I want to set the below css to the div using jQuery:

```
Transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)
```

But that div has already inline style

```
Transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
```

When I am assigning the css through jQuery, it is not accepting.

```
$(“#myDiv”).css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)");
```

How to resolve the issue?

**Update:**

I'm also using the JS file at the bottom of the page(i.e below `</body>` tag). I have written the code in **$(window).load(function(){})** event and it is applying. 
But I'm having flickering effect due to position interchanging.

Comment: Can you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your problem so I can see the broader scope here?

Comment: Why don't you create a class for it and add it to it using `.addClass()`?

Comment: You could replace the whole attribute: `(“#myDiv”).attr("style", "transform:matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)");`

Comment: Its working for me check http://jsfiddle.net/hy5FJ/

Comment: jQuery sets the styles with just regular JS, as in element.style, and that actually inserts the styles inline, so setting the same CSS property with javascript as any style already present inline, will overwrite the inline style, and the one added with javascript takes presedence. The only styles not easily overridden are styles set in a stylesheet with !important. If it's not working, you're doing something else wrong, as in the syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myDiv").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)");
}, 1000);
```

I set the timeout to be able of see the change.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnaDC/)**

I would say that the problem is because of this weird quotes you have around #myDiv.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong quotes in you selector: `$(“#myDiv”)`

`$("#myDiv").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300)");` works fine for me now:

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/xQ3bJ/

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `!important` to the css rule, as in:

```
$(“#myDiv”).css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 461, 300) !important");
```

Comment: `!important` is not supported by JQuery as you are using it . Moreover inline css overrides css classes

Comment: You **can not** add !important to the CSS in javascript, at least not like that